# How to avoid different branch checkout in slave node in Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

1. I'm running a pipeline which have multiple stages. These stages runs in sequence and also these stages run on slave nodes.
2. Two branches `develop` and `master` are configured in branches to build.
3. Now problem starts, when a developer commits to a branch, let say, to `develop` branch
4. This triggers job and pipeline starts stage # 1, which runs on jenkins master node.
5. While first stage is running, meanwhile develop pushed code to second branch `master` too.
6. Now when pipeline reaches to stage #2, which runs on jenkins slave # 1, this time, because latest commit was made on `master` branch, hence it checkout the code from `master` rather then `develop` which was build in previous stage # 1

Now this contains code mix up in final build at the end of pipeline.

Is there some way to force checkout at slave to same commit which was checkedout in previous stage in master jenkins node?

Any help would be appreciate :)

Comment: Is the problem that the checkouts are in the same directory, so the two jobs are overwriting each other? Or that the job doesn't specify the commit that's being processed, so tries to guess based on what was updated recently?

Comment: this is `one` pipeline job, which runs different stages in different jenkins nodes.  For example, stage # 1 runs on jenkins master node, and stage # 2 runs on jenkins slave.
Now problem is, while stage #1 on master, checkedout code from develop branch and stage #1 is building code, a developer made commit to `master` branch. Now when stage #1 finishes and stage #2 checkout code on jenkins slave node, it checkout code from `master` branch.

Comment: Why would stage #2 need to decide which code to checkout? Normally, a build is for a specific commit ID, and that commit ID should be available to all stages, they shouldn't need to guess what to build based on external information.

Comment: yes, it should be but it is not.
if next stage is running on another node, then somehow checkout code taken from another commit which was made while stage#1 was running. you can test it too.

Comment: I don't really understand how a CI script could even _know_ that new commits existed, and on a completely different branch. Perhaps you could [edit] the question to include some more details of the pipeline, such as your Jenkinsfile? Otherwise, it's quite hard to guess what you've done and what you could do differently.